# Can the same task be called from within a task?

Tags: c#, try-catch, task

```
private List<NetConnection> connectionList = new List<NetConnection>();
private Task ProcessTask;

public void Start(int PortNumber, int RepeatTime)
{
    repeatTime = RepeatTime;
    portNumber = PortNumber;
    ProcessTask = DeviceControl(repeatTime);
}

private async Task DeviceControl(int RepeatTime)
{
    NetConnection Server= new NetConnection();
    Server.Start(portNumber);
    Server.OnConnect += Server_OnConnect;
    Server.OnDisconnect += Server_OnDisconnect;
    Server.OnDataReceived += Server_OnDataReceived;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (NetConnection connection in connectionList)
            {
                connection.Send(new byte['a']);
            }
            await Task.Delay(RepeatTime);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                 
        ProcessTask = DeviceControl(repeatTime);
    }
}
```

I have a method that checks socket connections and I want the method to be restarted when an error occurs.

What if I want to restart the same task when an error occurs?

Comment: Recursive taak based methods are just that. Technically you won't restart the task (that is impossible) but you're kicking off a new one and you assign that new task to `ProcessTask`

Comment: Sorry.  I wrote wrong. So this call will create confusion?

Comment: No it won't, but it does keep references to `server` all the time. I would refactor the code in such a way that the recursion is not necessary. How is `DeviceControl` Initially called and what role does `ProcessTask` play?

Comment: I edited the code. ProcessTask does not have a role. Maybe later.

Comment: It's not clear whether you really are asking about a recursive task, or you really are asking how to implement a task that can be retried. It seems more likely the latter is more useful. See duplicates. As they explain, you can't restart a given task, but you can restart a new one, or make the current one retry its logic.

Comment: Note that in the example you wrote, the task isn't restarted; you replace the old with with a new one in the `ProcessTask` variable, and then complete the old one. Anything that has already starting waiting on that task (i.e. retrieved the reference) is going to observe the completion of the old one, and won't observe the newly started task, unless you add logic to check how the old task completed. To make matters more confusing, in your current example the task _only_ completes on failure, making it unclear why you bother at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) for retry mechanism.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var polly = Policy
                .Handle<Exception>()
                .RetryAsync(3, (ex, retryCount, context) => Console.WriteLine($"Try {retryCount}"));

    var result = polly.ExecuteAsync(async () => await DeviceControl(10));
    Console.WriteLine(result);

}

private static Task DeviceControl(int repeatTime)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```